# Kaa Admin ReST client for java

Tags: rest, kaa

There have been questions about the jar and dependencies of the REST capabilities, but I remember seeing that the documentation of future releases would include information on the admin-rest-client type. Which functions does the client support?

I'm referring to this previous answer-- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kaaproject/BUVMRTgy99c
What are the methods supported for AdminClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details you can find in the source code of [AdminClient](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/server/common/admin-rest-client/src/main/java/org/kaaproject/kaa/server/common/admin/AdminClient.java). There are methods from [controller](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/tree/master/server/node/src/main/java/org/kaaproject/kaa/server/admin/controller) classes. Also, you can refer to the [Server REST APIs](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/) documentation.